# How to get time difference in ('h:m:s') between two times which are already in this format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, time, php-carbon

I want to get difference between two times in `hour:min:sec` format. For Example starting time `02:00:00` and ending time `02:30:00` Difference should be `00:30:00`

I tried to use Carbon but i think it support different format

`<td> {{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($sales->created_at))}}</td>`

I want to get difference in `hour:min:sec` input  would also be in same format

Comment: You can use format(), Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s')->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($sales->created_at)->format('H:i:s'))

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: giving me this error Call to a member function diff() on string

Comment: i thin format() it in string

Comment: Yeah my bad you can use, Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s')->diff(\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$sales->created_at))

Comment: Now this error
`Too few arguments to function Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat(), 1 passed`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine,

```
$diff = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diff(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('12:50:35'));
```

This will return DateInterval object,

```
DateInterval {#242 ▼
  interval: + 11:18:14.006875
  +"y": 0
  +"m": 0
  +"d": 0
  +"h": 11
  +"i": 18
  +"s": 14
  +"f": 0.006875
  +"weekday": 0
  +"weekday_behavior": 0
  +"first_last_day_of": 0
  +"invert": 0
  +"days": 0
  +"special_type": 0
  +"special_amount": 0
  +"have_weekday_relative": 0
  +"have_special_relative": 0
}
```

Then you can get diff in hours, seconds, minutes, days etc.

```
$diff->h, $diff->i, $diff->s, $diff->days
```

So your input would be,

```
$diff->h .':'. $diff->i .':'. $diff->s
```

Otherwise you can use,

```
$diffInhours = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInHours(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('12:50:35');
$diffInMinutes = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('12:50:35'));
```

Or [many other ways](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Carbon `diff()` function returns a **DateInterval** Object.

Your expected result can be retrieve from DateInterval object by calling `format()` function.

```php
<td>
    {{ $timeDifference = now()->diff($sales->created_at)->format('%h:%i:%s') }}
</td>
```